# How can I convert this timestamp function from php to C#?

Tags: c#, php

I need to convert this php code to C#;

```
public function timestamp() {
    return intval(microtime(TRUE) * 1000);
}
```

I understand its related to the number of microseconds since the unix epoch but what I don't understand is the result I get.  When I run a script with this code;

```
<?php
echo (microtime(true) * 1000);
echo '<br>';
echo intval(microtime(true) * 1000);
?>
```

It outputs;

```
1422560055622.8
925880646
```

Now, I can get 1422560055622.8 via C# code just fine but I don't understand is how that is being converted to 925880646 via intval.  I would expect intval to convert it to 1422560055622 or 2147483647 (being the max for a 32 bit integer).

More importantly how can I replicate this function in C#?

EDIT: Sounds like there is an issue with PHP on my server, as other people have replicated the code and not had the same results.  I am able to convert the code now, if anyone would like to provide an answer as to why this is happening (as I am still curious) I will accept it.  Otherwise I'll answer it myself when I'm able.

Comment: on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com your code tested seams to show normal values, what's your php version ?

Comment: @Marius.C Version is 5.5.12.  I'm using Wamp (www.wampserver.com/en/)

Comment: note that if you're on a 32bit php, then your maximum possible intval will be 2**31 -> 2,147,483,647.

Comment: @MarcB Yeah I mentioned that in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a comment followup: It's because you're on a 32bit PHP install, and PHP is simply dropping any overflow bits:

```
10100101100110111001011111101000101000110 - 1422560055622
           110111001011111101000101000110 - 925880646
        210987654321098765432109876543210
        333222222222211111111110000000000
```

Note how the bits line up nicely, and since your "wrong" PHP number has 2 leading 0bits, they're simply dropped when the number's converted to a displayable string.

Answer (score 2):

it's a same function in c# i wish be a helpful fro you

```
using System;
class StackOverFlow
{
static void Main()
{
    Console.Write(StackOverFlow.TimeStamp());
}
public static decimal TimeStamp()
{
    decimal returner = DateTime.Now.Millisecond * 1000;

    return returner;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `round` your `microtime(true)*1000`.

Or just simply cast it as integer `$yourint = (int)(microtime(true)*1000);`

But I also tried your code, and returned the expected value. Maybe you're using an older version of php, what can't handle **float** or **decimal** in `intval` function.

Comment: Php version is 5.5.12. I'm using Wamp (www.wampserver.com/en/)

Comment: It's strange. Then try with round, or cast as integer. It should work with 1 of them.

Comment: Thanks but as I say in my question, I'm not looking to perfect the php code but figure out why it's doing that and convert to C#.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I misunderstood you.